# How to calculate the intensity of a light when using the ray model?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, intensity

[image]

Suppose that there is a point light source with power $P$. We are interested in a single light ray visualised in the above picture. The ray travels a distance $r_1$ and encounters a surface. The ray comes in angle $\theta$ and is reflected in the same angle. Some of its intensity of course is lost, say, a proportion $\alpha$ .

The reflected ray travels the distance $r_2$. Now how would you calculate the intensity of a reflected ray at the point given in the figure, or does it even make sense to talk about the intensity of a single ray?

Comment: It kinda makes no sense but you could do $I=I_0\frac{1-\alpha}{(r_1+r_2)^2}$

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a ray.  A ray could be a vector at a point in space perpendicular to the wave front at that point, or a ray could be a pencil of light (somewhat like a laser).  A ray could also be the path that a photon takes.  That picture is useful sometimes, but it gets difficult if you look too closely into what you mean by "photon".  Despite all that, I think the suggestion by @naturallyInconsistent might be what you want.  It tells you the intensity of the field at the end of $r_2$ due to a point source at the beginning of $r_1$. ...

Comment: ... But watch out:  if more than one ray terminates at a point you have to consider the coherence between the fields that the rays represent.  You may or may not be able to add the intensities.   The interpretation, validity, and usefulness of a figure like the one you provide depends on what you plan to do with the picture.

Comment: I mean ray as in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_(optics). I am trying to simulate intensity measurements.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Is $I_0$ the intensity at distance $r_1$ before the reflection?

Answer (score 0):

The intensity of a single light ray doesn't make sense because a ray is a direction of travel. But it's perfectly possible to give the intensity of reflected light from P passing the marked point, Q (say).

Let us assume that $P$ is the power emitted in the visible spectrum. Half the power hits the mirror so power $(1-\alpha)\tfrac 12 P$ is reflected and, to the viewer (at Q, for example), appears to come from the virtual image of the source. Q lies  on a hemispherical wavefront of radius $(r_1+r_2)$ over which the power is spread, so the intensity at Q is... Over to you!

Comment: for the variation of intensity along *a* ray, please, see above.

Comment: @hyportnex  Thank you. This is probably a silly question, but can one easily apply what's in your answer to the specific question about a reflected ray?

Comment: it is not silly at all, I was silly to have forgotten to add it in... yes, an easier way is in a homogeneous medium, see the referenced section in Born&Wolf. According to Eq.36 from the reference $\mathcal I \propto \frac {1}{R_1R_2}$ where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the principal curvatures and $\frac{1}{R_1R_2}$ is the Gaussian curvature of the wavefront represented by the eikonal $\mathcal S =const$. Let the source, reflection and observation points be $\mathcal {P_0, P_1,P_2}$ . Now apply this between  $\mathcal P_0 \to \mathcal P_1$ and $\mathcal P_1 \to \mathcal P_2$....

Comment: and in between use the reflection/absorption coefficient $\alpha$ at $\mathcal P_1$ as you have indicated it to estimate the initial intensity for the second leg.

Answer (score 0):

A point source emits some total amount of energy in some short period of time. This energy spreads out in an expanding spherical shell. Intensity $I$ is the energy per unit area.

A ray hits a point. You need to think about area. So you need to think about more than one ray.

In a ray model, you can think about a point source as emitting N rays, and each ray representing $1/N^{th}$ of the energy. So $ I \propto$ the number of rays per unit area.

For an expanding spherical shell, the separation between adjacent rays is proportional to $r$. The area of shell closest to a particular ray $\propto r^2$. So $I \propto 1/r^2$.

---

The mirror absorbs a fraction of the energy. But it doesn't change how rays spread out. You get the same rays at the image point if you replace the mirror with a window (that absorbs the same energy) and put the source on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Within the asymptotic high frequency approximation that is usually called geometrical optics it is possible to define what is meant by ray intensity. One starts with writing the solutions of Maxwell's equation in a linear isotropic medium as $\mathbf E_0(\mathbf r)=\mathbf e(\mathbf r) e^{\mathfrak j \kappa_0 \mathcal S(\mathbf r)}$ and $\mathbf H_0(\mathbf r)=\mathbf h(\mathbf r) e^{\mathfrak j \kappa_0 \mathcal S(\mathbf r)}$, where $\kappa_0 = \omega/c$ and $\mathcal S$ is the so-called eikonal whose gradient is the ray vector. If you substitute these into Maxwell's equation, and let $\omega \to \infty$ or equivalently $\kappa_0 \to \infty$, then you get the following, see sections 3.1.1 and 3.1.2 in [Born&Wolf](https://archive.org/details/principlesofopti0000born/page/110/mode/2up?view=theater):

$$\nabla \mathcal S \times \mathbf h  + \epsilon \mathbf e = 0\\
\nabla \mathcal S \times \mathbf e  - \mu \mathbf h = 0\\
\mathbf e \cdot  \nabla \mathcal S =0\\
\mathbf h \cdot  \nabla \mathcal S =0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

From $\eqref{1}$ it follows that $$n^2=\epsilon\mu = |\nabla \mathcal S |^2.$$ The rays are the lines tangential to the gradients $\nabla \mathcal S$ of the eikonal, in other words, the rays are the envelope curves of the tangents.
The vectors $\nabla \mathcal S$, $\mathbf e$ and $\mathbf h$ are orthogonal to each other and thus  the direction of the Poynting vector is along the unit *ray-vector* $\mathbf s$ defined by $n\mathbf s = \nabla \mathcal S$. In this formalism the points of a ray when parametrized with its line element $\mathbf r (s)$ satisfy the differential equation $n\frac{d\mathbf r}{ds}=\nabla \mathcal S$ from which one gets $\frac{d}{ds}\left(n\frac{d\mathbf r}{ds}\right) = \nabla n$ ; this is Snell's law of refraction.

Now regarding the intensity $\mathcal I$ of the ray, it can be shown that we have:

$$\nabla^2 \mathcal S + \nabla \ln \frac{\mathcal I}{n}=0$$ which can be integrated to
$$\frac{\mathcal I(\mathcal S_2)}{\mathcal I(\mathcal S_1)}=\frac{n(\mathcal S_2)}{n(\mathcal S_1)}\exp\left(-\int_{\mathcal S_1}^{\mathcal S_2}\frac{\nabla^2 \mathcal S}{n}ds\right) \tag{2}\label{2}$$

In $\eqref{2}$ $\mathcal S_{1,2}$ are the endpoints of the ray along which we integrate with a line element $ds$. Note that $d\tau = \frac{ds}{n}$ is the infinitesimal amount of time (normalized with $c$) that it takes for the light to move in the medium a distance of $ds$.

Comment: Correct, but incommensurate with the level of the question.